# Open chromium full screen on start up with login

Tags: pi-3, chromium

I have a bit more difficult situation with chromium in full screen.
I need to open chromium in full screen then log in to specific site to show employees stats. (username/password is saved)
But every time chromium closes ( restart/etc) I need to press ENTER again to log in then open link again, but I want this process to be fully automated.
I thought to use @xdotool key KP_ENTER command to approve it, but this is not working.
currently it all looks like this :

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi  
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi  
@xscreensaver -no-splash  
point-rpi  
@xset s off  
@xset -dpms    
@xset s noblank  
@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen http://site/Admin/Picking/PickersLeaderboard?shopCode=R602   
@xdotool key KP_ENTER  
@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen http://site/Admin/Picking/PickersLeaderboard?shopCode=R602
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem using scripts and the sleep function.

I used 4 scripts to achieve what I asked in question. In each script I added `SLEEP xx` in start with increasing value. In autostart I just added path/script to execute these scripts one after another.

Comment: Would you care to post the script?

Comment: I used 4 scripts to achieve what I asked in question. in each script i added SLEEP xx in start with increasing value. in autostart I just added path/script to execute these scripts one after another.